Angular: difference between using signal and simple class member for holding state
I am using signals in Angular 18 for small local states. I don't understand what the difference is with a normal class member. Let's take a simple toggle:
Example 1
@Component({...})
export class ToggleComponent {
  toggleState: boolean = false;

  toggle() {
    this.toggleState = !this.toggleState;
  }
}

Example 2
@Component({...})
export class ToggleComponent {
  toggleState = signal(false);

  toggle() {
    this.toggleState.set(!this.toggleState());
  }
}

For this example, what is the difference between those two approaches?

Check this link

As a rule of thumb, signals will mark your component as dirty and schedule change detection.
Signals should represent states, that when updated, should trigger a change detection cycle.

Here is a simple app (stackblitz) to demonstrate why it really matters. Notice ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.
In 1 second the result is "2 1 1".
In 2 seconds the result is still "2 1 1".
In 3 seconds the result is finally "2 2 2".
import 'zone.js';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    {{ foo() }}
    {{ bar }}
    {{ baz() }}
  `,
})
export class App {
  foo = signal(1);
  bar = 1;
  baz = signal(1);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    timer(1000).subscribe(() => this.foo.set(2));
    timer(2000).subscribe(() => (this.bar = 2));
    timer(3000).subscribe(() => this.baz.set(2));
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);


Imagine you have three components. Let's say Header, Sidebar and Main content. And an event changes the (Update) value which only affects Main content.

Zone.js All three components (Header, Sidebar, Main Content) are checked for changes.
Signals Only the Main Content component is checked and updated

In summary Zone.js which is traditional state management trigger a global change detection cycle, and Signals Only triggers change detection for the specific parts of the template that depend on the signal.
In your case: The child component can update a signal that the parent component depends on. Only the parts of the parent component that depend on the signal will be updated.
In traditional approach the child component can emit an event to the parent component, which then updates its state. This will trigger a global change detection cycle

So the approach in which I can use simple members of the class, uses Zone.js?

This is a feature of OnPush more that signals.
